How to set an offset for adjustResize / imePadding?
He||o, using Kotlin and Compose, I created a Column in a Box, I use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in the manifest file
The Column's Modifier uses .align(Alignment.BottomCenter) and .offset(y = (-110).dp), it looks like this:

The Column's Modifier also uses .imePadding(), it looks like this when the keyboard is shown:

Is there some way to use some offset so when the keyboard appears, the Column goes lower?
So there is no space between the Login button and the keyboard

Please have a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79202589/8331157 Maybe it helps in your case. I think there should be no need to use a negative offset in your case.

Modifier.imePadding() is just a padding that changes based on keyboard height. If there are 100.dp space between a button it still be a 100.dp when keyboard is opened.
As mentioned in question you need to have a layout or offset Modifier that do not change position in parent, in OP's case there are no siblings but offset does not change position of siblings as padding does so it works unlike imePadding because when there is no space padding does not work as expected but it works as intended, because it's a padding modifier.

First you need to set
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

to be able to get keyboard size with
val density = LocalDensity.current
val imeBottom = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(density)

Create an offset Modifier that changes with keyboard height
fun Modifier.imeOffset(contentBottom: Int = 0) = composed {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val imeBottom = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(density)
    val navBarBottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(density)
    Modifier.offset {
        IntOffset(
            x =0,
            y = (-imeBottom + contentBottom + navBarBottom)
                .coerceAtMost(0)
        )
    }
}

contentBottom is the bottom position of Composable that this Modifier will be assigned to which is calculated with
.onPlaced {
    val parentHeight = it.parentLayoutCoordinates?.size?.height ?: 0
    bottom = (parentHeight - it.boundsInParent().bottom.toInt())
} 

Demo
@Composable
private fun ImeOffsetSample() {
    var bottom by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .systemBarsPadding()
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(y = (150).dp)
                .onPlaced {
                    if (bottom == 0) {
                        val parentHeight = it.parentLayoutCoordinates?.size?.height ?: 0
                        bottom = (parentHeight - it.boundsInParent().bottom.toInt())
                            .coerceAtLeast(0)
                    }
                }
                .imeOffset(bottom)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {

            var email by remember {
                mutableStateOf("")
            }

            var password by remember {
                mutableStateOf("")
            }

            TextField(
                value = email,
                onValueChange = { email = it },
                label = { Text("email") }
            )

            TextField(
                value = password,
                onValueChange = { password = it },
                label = { Text("password") }
            )

            Button(
                onClick = {}
            ) {
                Text("Login")
            }
        }
    }
}

Another sample with a Column that contains other Composbles above the child to be assigned with imeOffset. In this case padding would shrink last Compoasble(TextField and Button in Column) because the amount of space is Column height - imePadding which is not enough to fit last composable.

Button and TextField can be moved above keyboard even if whole Composable is filled with other sibling Composables.
@Composable
private fun ImeOffsetSample() {
    var bottom by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().systemBarsPadding()
    ) {

        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text("TopAppbar")
            }
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

            repeat(4) {
                SomeComposable()
                Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }

            repeat(7) {
                Text("Some Text")
                Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .onPlaced {
                        if (bottom == 0) {
                            val parentHeight = it.parentLayoutCoordinates?.size?.height ?: 0
                            bottom = (parentHeight - it.boundsInParent().bottom.toInt())
                                .coerceAtLeast(0)

                            println("Parent height: $parentHeight, bottom: $bottom")
                        }
                    }
                    .imeOffset(bottom)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                SomeComposable()
                Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier

                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Text("Login")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SomeComposable() {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("text") }
    )
}


I replaced by contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter and .offset(y = (-150).dp), otherwise the button was like shaking when switching text field (and anyway i really wanted the bottom as base)

I set it as arbitrary number for demonstration because my emulator height was bigger. And in real examples like Column with weight or full of content this also works because you are using offset to move specific content above keyboard. The important part here is using an offset and calculate space between the content

And for the animation part. Keyboard animation are not the best part of android, they are not synced with the content they push. However there is a keyboard animation synch option but not for Composables but Views. With some workaround you can make it smoother. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/sw-keyboard#synchronize-animation

You made my day <3
